# E488: Trailing characters: #### The source file for gvim

Tags: vim

I am getting the E488 error in gvim. My `.vimrc` file starts as follows

```
set guifont=Courier\ 10 Pitch\ 16

set backspace=2
set backspace=indent,eol,start
syntax on
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, you're missing a backslash in your first command:

```
set guifont=Courier\ 10\ Pitch\ 16
```

You can use `:let` here to avoid the escaping:

```
let &guifont = 'Courier 10 Pitch 16'
```

But that should have given you a `E518: Unknown option: Pitch\ 16` instead.

In any case, Vim has given you a line number / context information. You can also recall the startup errors via `:messages`. If all else fails, comment out / remove parts of your config until you find the bad line.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto for what Ingo Karkat said, but you can also use underscores in place of spaces (at least in the Win32 GUI).

Try reading through `:h guifont` and `:h E488` as well.